# Excel file created by poi API: data is there but only one row is viewable?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I used a simple code from online [code](http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=554) and I was able to call the method in the code in a for loop and passing it data and row number. The file is created properly, the file's size (after refreshing my file explorer) is changed upon each insert but when i am done I open the file and I can only see the first row in there and the moment i close it the size of the file decreases from 1.5MB to 5bytes. I opened the 1.5 MB file in notepadd++ (ofcourse it opened with byte characters) I could actually see the data that i have been writing into the file besides the first row, All my rows were there. but when i open in excel it doesnt.

Is there some thing I am missing here. At each insert into the excel file I am doing this :

```
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);
sampleWorkbook.write(fileOutputStream);
```

and after that in the finally block of the try block :

```
finally {
    /**
     * Close the fileOutputStream.
    */
    try {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but if the file size is changing and I can view the data in a notepad why is excel treating the rows other than the first one as temporary data (that is what I'm assuming it's doing as it reverts back to only 5 bytes when I close the file)? What's wrong here?

Thanks for your help, in advance.

syed.

Comment: Small style note about your `finally{...}` block: there is no need to call `flush()`, it is called during `close()`. Also, if you use Java 7, you can just write `try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true)){ /* code here */ }`, after this block stream will be closed automatically.

Comment: @FrozenSpider : nice... I knowwww Java 7 is sooo cool ( since Java 6 developers can actually use kewl for java lol..) but we are on 6 still. would love to work on 7 tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that xls isn't a simple format and adding a row into a xls doesn't mean appending several bytes in the end of the file. The new data is inserted in the middle of the file so you have to completely rewrite the whole file.
You code sample just writes another workbook after already existing workbook, which makes file content invalid. So when you open it in Excel it automatically corrects file content removing all added data except the first workbook.

Use this code sample:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream (path);
Workbook sampleWorkbook;
try{
  sampleWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook (in);//or XSSFWorkbook depending on whether you use xls or xlsx
} finally
{
  in.close ();
}

//Add some rows into the workbook

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (path);
try{
  sampleWorkbook.write (out);
} finally
{
  out.close ();
}
```

Comment: So If i was doing a new file write just the FileOutPutStream wud have been sufficient, but When i need to add data to excel file i need to get an FileInputStream and then from there add it and then create a new outputStream for teh same file and re write the whole workbook to the file.Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it was working fine: but on some inserts (or most specifically on new HSSFWORKBOOK(new fileinputstream(filename))) it is giving an exception : org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$Lef
toverDataException: Initialisation of record 0x3C left 5414 bytes remaining still to be read. Is there some thing i am missing : I am usign poi-3.6-20091214.jar. besides that my last record is never written like I am writing 4 strings in a row, my fourth cell is coming empty in watever data is being written.

Comment: Could it be ebcuase the data might have some Arabic characters ?? hmm is this the same question or should I post a new one on this issue...

Comment: I guess POI reacts this way on several workbooks written into one file. For the code to work you should start with a valid workbook. I suggest you try to make as much as possible changes in the workbook before saving and re-opening it. I'm not sure how POI handles Arabic characters, though I suppose it's a question for a separate discussion.

Comment: Naah it had nothing to do with arabic characters. it was because my 12th or 13th insert had some large object data and excel wasnt able to digust such an insert and started having a concussion/constipational issues. so the next writes just went thru an exception as the last write wasnt completede and died trying..  Thanks for the answer tho I was using only one workbook in one file and one sheet. just added rows into the wb.

Answer (score 0):

Might not that relevant to your question, but for easy Excel generating, it's recommended to use JXLS (http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) which is built on top of POI. The beautiful part of JXLS is it enable you to create an Excel template (using Excel of course), and then you just put the data into the template. It supports basic logic operation including if else and loop.

Comment: Do u have a tutorial or an example that I can look at ... the source page is only definitions

Comment: It's a cool thing: allows you to move you cycle from Java into the template. Though I don't think it allows you to just open a Workbook from a file, edit it and then save it or update a workbook by a template..

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford commercial solution take a look at [Templater](http://templater.info/). It's very easy to use. Disclaimer: I'm the author.